# How to grep logs from specific date

Tags: regex, linux

I have the following log format:

```
[23:34:43.669] Notice [2] Some notice on line 21
```

Line by line, and I want to use grep to find only those lines that are from 15:00 to 21:00.

How can I do that?

I've been trying something like `grep '\[21:.*?\].*?' file.txt`

But it returns empty output. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do 15:00 to 20:59 if that's not a problem for you.

You can use the following grep pattern:

```
grep '\[\(1[5-9]\|20\).*\?\].*' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works if I remove the `?`:

`grep '\[21:.*\].*' file.txt`

I think your mistake is combining `*` and `?`, which would make the `?` apply to the `*`. You should rather use one only. For reference about `?`in grep regexes, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression).

Comment: Using `.*?` is not a mistake, it's how you do a non-greedy match. The problem was that it needs to be escaped when using grep with the backslash: `\?`